# how to access fieldset control in c#

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have below code:

```
<fieldset id="preFacts">
    <div id="divstructures" runat="server" style="width: 100%;">
        <div id="divleft" runat="server" style="width: 48%; float:left">
            <label>Desk:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesk" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>
            <label>Desk2:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesk2" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>
        </div>
         <div id="divright" runat="server" style="width: 48%; float:right">
            <label>Desk3:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesk3" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>
            <label>Desk4:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesk4" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**CSS:**

```
fieldset#preFacts label
{
     width: 20em;   
}
```

now in c# if condition = true i want to display divright(new controls) along with divleft(existing controls) or if condition = false then i want to display divleft(existing controls) always in center using above css(fieldset#preFacts label).

how can i set width: 10em;(fieldset#preFacts label) when the condition is true in c#(dynamically) so that both div's display properly left and right.

Answer (score 1):

fieldset is not a control but an HTML tag. You can use

```
<fieldset id="preFacts" runat="server">
```

to make it visible to ASP.NET.
You could implement a multiview or set the CSS in your code-behind when the page is loaded.

Also, you could take `divright` in your code-behind and set its style to `display:none;` When your condition is met. See here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.style(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ved=0CB8QFjABahUKEwjptP3HlcfHAhWG1RoKHclpDV8&usg=AFQjCNEJS7adTj2Jh1eFqMPU0IcmOa8qNw

Yet, you might consider to move your intention away from server side code. Processing your requirements via client code is the better approach today.

Comment: Thxs for your reply. How can i set width of fieldset#prefacts either server/client side?

Comment: Server side using the Style property of the control. Or client side using style property and include `width: YYYpx;`

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd avoid your inline styles. They will generally take precedence over any other class you apply, which makes it more difficult to work with. Also note that the IDs you're setting on server controls may change unless you also set `ClientIDMode="Static"`, which might prevent your CSS from being applied correctly.

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to achieve, but here's one approach to make the 'left' side take up the whole fieldset if your condition is false, or half the width if true:

**CSS:**
Here, I'm setting a few classes, rather than depending on IDs.

```
.divstructures { width: 100%; }
.divfalse  { width: 100%; }
.divleft  { width: 48%; float: left; }
.divright { width: 48%; float: right; }
```

**ASPX:**
This is using an `asp:Panel` control instead of the inner `div`s. There are many other approaches you could take:

```
<fieldset id="preFacts">
    <div id="divstructures" runat="server" style="width: 100%;">
        <asp:Panel id="divleft" runat="server">
            <label>Desk:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesk" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>
            <label>Desk2:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesk2" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>
         </asp:Panel>
         <asp:Panel id="divright" CssClass="divright" runat="server">
            <label>Desk3:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesk3" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>
            <label>Desk4:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesk4" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**C#:**
Here the panel style and visibility is set based on your condition:

```
...
bool condition = true; // or whatever way you need to set this value
...
divright.Visible = condition;
divleft.CssClass = condition ? "divleft" : "divfalse";
...
```

You may need to tweak the CSS to get the exact effect you're looking for.